# How can I exclude a specific dictionary key when generating random keys from that dictionary?

Tags: python

I am learning python and working on this problem. Basically the second character that I am generating needs to be a random character from one of my dictionaries but it can't be the same character in the sentence.

I have looked into the random.choice() python method and I can't really find anything to help me exclude any elements. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

```
import random
def dict_practice(dict):
     for chars in dict:
          print('{0} and {1} fought over who could wear {2}.'.format(chars, random.choice(list(dict)), dict[chars]))
     
castaways = {
     "Gilligan": "red",
     "Skipper": "blue",
     "Professor": "khaki",
     "Mary Ann": "gingham",
     "Ginger": "sequins",
     "Thurston": "an ascot",
     "Lovee": "a gardener's hat"
 }

scoobies = {
  "Scooby": "a blue collar",
  "Shaggy": "green",
  "Velma": "orange",
  "Daphne": "purple",
  "Fred": "an ascot"
 }

dict_practice(castaways)
dict_practice(scoobies)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the cases you want to see and not see

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python random.choice method without repeats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128703/python-random-choice-method-without-repeats)

Answer (score 1):

1 solution can be to remove the `chars` from the list of the dictionary keys, then passing the list in `random.choice()`

```
import random
def dict_practice(dict1):
     for chars in dict1:
          x=list(dict1)
          x.remove(chars)
          print('{0} and {1} fought over who could wear {2}.'.format(chars, random.choice(x), dict1[chars]))
     print("---------------------")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
i = []
def dict_practice(dict):
     for chars in dict:
        if dict[chars] in i:
            pass
        else:
            i.append(dict[chars])
            print('{0} and {1} fought over who could wear {2}.'.format(chars, random.choice(list(dict)), dict[chars]))

castaways = {
     "Gilligan": "red",
     "Skipper": "blue",
     "Professor": "khaki",
     "Mary Ann": "gingham",
     "Ginger": "sequins",
     "Thurston": "an ascot",
     "Lovee": "a gardener's hat"
 }

scoobies = {
  "Scooby": "a blue collar",
  "Shaggy": "green",
  "Velma": "orange",
  "Daphne": "purple",
  "Fred": "an ascot"
 }

dict_practice(castaways)
dict_practice(scoobies)

print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works without copying or modifying the original dict in each iteration:

```py
import random

def dict_practice(characters):
    # Create a list with the name and the color of each character
    items = list(characters.items())

    # Iterate over the name and the color of each character
    for name1, color1 in items:
        # Picks a random item from the list of the names and colors
        # until the picked name is different from the original name
        while True:
            name2, color2 = random.choice(items)
            if name1 != name2:
                break
            
        print('{0} and {1} fought over who could wear {2}.'.format(
            name1, name2, characters[random.choice((name1, name2))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat `dict.keys()` as a set and remove an element from it by simply subtracting it. This means you can pass the characters minus the current character to `random.coice` leaving you with:

```
def dict_practice(d):
    for char in d:
        remaining = d.keys() - set([char])
        other = random.choice(list(remaining))
        print(f'{char} and {other} fought over who could wear {d[char]}')
```

This will give you random characters without mutating your original data nor setting up a loop/check scenario.